Solving the IVP differential equation using variable separation
Given the differential equation $$xy \log(\frac{x}{y})dx+(y^2-x^2\log(\frac{x}{y}))dy=0$$ where $y(1)=0$? Solve it using variable separation .
I have tried the problem using the routine method of substitution of $y=kx$ where k is some function. But I am getting stumped after proceeding as I am getting terms like $ln(\frac{x}{y})$ which is becoming undefined. I am facing this problem while solving the solution . What will be the procedure to solve this problem . A detailed solution would be appreciated .

How does really look your equation? Check a real look of your equation with that you have written.

Yes I know , this is the exact question given to me. I am unable to figure out the question as we are getting undefined values like $ln0$ or $1/0$ like this . @VadimChernetsov

I mean exactly this look $xy \log(\frac{x}{y})dx+(y^2-x^2\log(\frac{x}{y})dy=0$. Check a real equation with that you have written.

Can you solve the problem . I know the equation has $ln\frac{x}{y}$ in it but even after simplifying I am getting the same thing so is the question wrong or I am missing some algebraic manipulation. @VadimChernetsov

I think I have corrected my equation. Please can anyone proceed after this???

It might be that decades ago there was a hand-written ur-version of this task that had $y(1)=\Large e$ and that over a series of misreadings this evolved to $y(1)=0$. It would be helpful if you could ask for clarification.

We have the ODE
$$x\cdot y\left(x\right)\cdot \mathrm{log}\left(\frac{x}{y\left(x\right)}\right)+\left(y\left(x\right)^{2}-x^{2}\cdot \mathrm{log}\left(\frac{x}{y\left(x\right)}\right)\right)\cdot y'\left(x\right)=0$$
Performing the following transformation $x=\xi,y\left(x\right)=\frac{\xi}{\eta\left(\xi\right)}$ yields
$$\frac{\left(\xi  \left(\eta \! \left(\xi \right)^{2} \ln\! \left(\eta \! \left(\xi \right)\right)-1\right) \left(\frac{d}{d \xi}\eta \! \left(\xi \right)\right)+\eta \! \left(\xi \right)\right) \xi^{2}}{\eta \! \left(\xi \right)^{4}}=0$$
Separating the variables and integrating
$$\int \left(\eta\cdot \ln\left(\eta\right)-\frac{1}{\eta}\right) d\eta=-\int \frac{1}{\xi} d\xi$$
$$\frac{\eta^{2} \ln\! \left(\eta \right)}{2}-\frac{\eta^{2}}{4}-\ln\! \left(\eta \right)=k-\ln\! \left(\xi \right)$$
Resubstition $\xi=x, \eta=\frac{x}{y}$, we get the implicit solution with integration constant $k$
$$\frac{x^{2} \ln\! \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{2 y^{2}}-\frac{x^{2}}{4 y^{2}}-\ln\! \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=k-\ln\! \left(x\right)$$
For $x=1, y(1)=y_1$ we get
$$\frac{\ln\! \left(\frac{1}{y_{1}}\right)}{2 y_{1}^{2}}-\frac{1}{4 y_{1}^{2}}-\ln\! \left(\frac{1}{y_{1}}\right)=k$$
with the solution
$$k=\frac{-4 \ln\! \left(\frac{1}{y_{1}}\right) y_{1}^{2}+2 \ln\! \left(\frac{1}{y_{1}}\right)-1}{4 y_{1}^{2}}$$
With $y_1=y(1)=e$ we get
$$k=1-\frac{3 {\mathrm e}^{-2}}{4}$$
Plot the implicit solution for $y(1)=e$

